# Как добавить в git решения существующий проект

Tags: visual-studio, git

Есть решение в VS2017 c контролем версий на Git, все исправно фиксируется и работает. Возникла необходимость добавить существующий проект в это решение. Добавил, но так и не разобрался как включить этот проект в систему контроля версий. Есть какие идеи? Или все таки надо скопировать проект в папку решения?

Comment: Вам нужно открыть вкладку "Изменения" в командном обозревателе и там добавить к фиксации все новые файлы. (Точные названия элементов интерфейса сейчас не вспомню).

Comment: @mymedia вот как раз таки в этой вкладке у меня новых файлов и не видно. Система видит что файл решения изменился. но не видит новый проект в решении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов несколько. Поместить существующий проект в отдельный репозиторий и добавить это репозиторий как [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8).

Скопировать проект в репозиторий решением и потом добавить его командой

```
git add
```

Затем сохранить изменения в репозиторий

```
git commit
```

Comment: вот копировать не хотелось бы. Проект этот существует отдельно и развивается, и копировать каждый раз как то не круто чтоли)

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov тогда используйте первый вариант.

Comment: Почитал по вашей ссылке - это то что нужно.